# rpart: Is training data required

Tags: r, rpart

I have a problem to understand some basics, so I'm stuck with a regression tree. 
I use a classification tree by rpart to check the influence of environmental parameters on a tree growth factor I measured.
Long story short:

What is the purpose of splitting data into training and test data and (when) do I need it? My searches showed examples in which they either don't do it or do it, but I can't find the backstory. Is it just to verify the pruning?

Thank you ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split into training and test data before training the model. The training data helps the model *learn*, while the test data helps *validate* the model.

The split is done before running the model, and the model must be retrained when there is some fine tuning or change.

As you might know, the general process for postpruning is the following:

```
1) Split data into training & test (validation) sets

2) Build decision tree from training set

3) For every non-leaf node N, prune the subtree rooted by N and
replace with the majority class. Then test accuracy with a
validation set. This validation set could be the one defined before
or not.
```

This all means that you are probably on the right track and that yes, the whole dataset has probably been used to test the accuracy of the pruning.

Comment: A late thank you very much! I mastered it now, but my modell looses all the nodes through pruning, so that only 1 node remains. After testing the mean and sd of the pruned set is really better, just looks weird :D